# SQL REPLACE function

Tags: sql, db2

I would like to replace a string of characters in one table from another.

I currently have  table1 with ssn, scrambledssn as columns. I also have another table with ssn,blob. the picture below is what I need table2 to look like after I run the sql I provided. the blob column has the ssn in the data and i need to mask it.  any help with my sql would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
MERGE INTO Table2 AS F
USING
(
    SELECT SSN, SCRAMBLEDSSN
    FROM TABLE1
    GROUP BY SSN,SCRAMBLEDSSN
) AS CDM
    ON F.SSN = CDM.SSN          
WHEN MATCHED 
THEN
Replace 
    select(BLOB,SSN,CDM.SCRAMBLEDSSN)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify which part of string need to be alter in Replace function. You can achieve your desired result through this way..

```
UPDATE Table2 
SET  Table2.BLOB = Replace(Table2.BLOB,'222222222', Table1.SCRAMBLEDSSN)
FROM Table1, Table2 
WHERE Table1.SSN = Table2.SSN
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO HERE**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/501193)</kbd>